# Trying to not have repeating data (MySQL, php)

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly I am brand new to PHP and MySQL.

My goal is to display testimonies from students that are in the database. I realize that my code is probably WAYYY overcomplicated, but any help is much obliged. Currently, It is displaying the same result. I think it's because I call for the same thing. Idk I am very confused. Help please!!

```
<div class="block_main_testimonials">
    <h4>Student Corner</h4>
<?php   
// Connect to the file above here   
require "includes/connect.php";  

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ) ; 

?>
                        <div class="one_half">
                            <div class="block_testimonials_2">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <p>“<?php echo $info['quote'] ;?>”</p>

                                        <div class="tail"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="author">
                                      <p><?php echo $info['name'] ; ?>,<span class="position"> <a href="/<?php echo $info['url']" echo $info['department']; ?</a></span></p></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearboth"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Hi - most of all, your code is unreadable. You don't need all those `Print`statements, just use them when you need to echo PHP variables / use PHP logic.

Comment: Check out mysql manuals for `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT` and then make sure that you need them here.

Comment: Appreciate this!! I will re-code and post again!

Comment: get rid of the Group By, the rest is fine.

Comment: you're using `group by` with no aggregate functions, and are limiting the results to the first row found only, which will always be the SAME id.

Comment: @moonwave99 - How's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but you don't want to use the [`GROUP BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html).

- **If you want to select all entries, use:**

  ```
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials`");
  ```
- **If you want to select one random entry, use:**

  ```
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
  ```

  and get rid of the `while` loop:

  ```
  $info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
  ```
- **If you want to select a certain number of random entries, use:**

  ```
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
  ```

  *Where `2` is number of results you want to recive. This will never return one row twice unless you have the exact same row stored twice in the database.*
- **If you want to select all entries in random order, use:**

  ```
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY RAND()");
  ```

---

**But please, if you're starting to learn PHP, [don't use the `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/1935077)**

Comment: How would I produce two random results that are not the same?